# Is the bond dissociation enthalpy of Cl-F greater than that of Cl-Cl?

Tags: bond, enthalpy, halides

In my book, it is mentioned that $\ce{Cl-F}$ has greater bond dissociation enthalpy than $\ce{Cl-Cl}$. Is it true? I know that interhalogen molecules usually have weaker bonds than dihalogen molecules except $\ce{F-F}$ molecule due to high electron-electron repulsion.

Comment: "I know that Interhalogen molecules usually have weaker bonds than dihalogen molecules" - in an X-Y molecule where X is the lighter halogen what are you comparing to, the dissociation energy for X-X, or Y-Y, or Sqrt( X-X * Y-Y ), or something else?

Comment: Comparing dissociation energy of XY with that of XX and YY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this](https://labs.chem.ucsb.edu/zakarian/armen/11---bonddissociationenergy.pdf) source, it can be seen that the $\ce {Cl-F}$ bond (BDE $\approx\pu{251 kJ/mol}$) is indeed stronger than the $\ce {Cl-Cl}$ bond (BDE $\approx\pu{243 kJ/mol}$). This can be explained by the partial ionic character of the $\ce {Cl-F}$ bond. The Pauling electronegativity value of fluorine ($\chi = 3.98$) is appreciably higher than that of chlorine ($\chi = 3.16$). Thus, there are significant partial positive and negative charges on the fluorine and chlorine atoms in the $\ce {ClF}$ molecule. Although the difference in orbital energies and size would mean that the covalent interaction between the chlorine $\ce {3p}$ and fluorine $\ce {2p}$ orbital would be less strong compared to that between 2 chlorine $\ce {3p}$ orbitals, the ionic character of the bond overcompensates for this and in fact, results in the $\ce {Cl-F}$ bond being stronger than the $\ce {Cl-Cl}$ bond.